# Eigenvalues Eigenvectors and bases of eigenspace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I was given the matrix 
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -5 & 4 \\ 2 & 0 & -3 \\ -1 & 2& -1  \end{pmatrix}
I'm not sure what to do after I get $-x^3 + 2x^2 - 17x + 9=0$.

Comment: It is very hard to read the matrix like this. Please improve the formatting, e.g. by using LaTeX / MathJax.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the matrix$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -5 & 4 \\ 2 & 0 & -3 \\ -1 & 2& -1  \end{pmatrix}$$That agrees with the characteristic polynomial you gave; but it only has 1 real root (i.e. eigenvalue).

Comment: Yes that's what i meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How do i find that 1 real root?

Comment: The eigenvalues are rather 'ugly'; even the single real root is. Is this an example you're supposed to do by hand? What is the exact question?

Comment: This was a test question I was assigned and when I got the test back I needed to know how to solve this.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the initial matrix correctly? You can check [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-x%5E3+%2B+2x%5E2+-+17x+%2B+9+%3D+0) for the real root, but it doesn't seem like one you want to find manually.

Comment: The problem is exactly like that just checked to make sure i copied it right. Thanks for the wolframalpha suggestion.

Comment: Solving cubic equations is hard; there is a cubic formula but you rarely want to actually use it, because it is complicated and numerically unstable. That said, sometimes you can use heuristics to piece together what's going on. In your case, your polynomial is positive at $-\infty$, positive at $0$, negative at $1$, and negative at $+\infty$. So there is a root somewhere in $[0,1]$, and the asymptotic behavior says there might be no others.

Comment: (Cont.) To check that, take the derivative. You get $-3x^2+4x-17$. This has no roots (since $16<4 \cdot 3 \cdot 17$). So there can only be one real root by Rolle's theorem. Since the derivative does not vanish there, the other two roots are complex. But it looks like none of these are rational, so I don't see how you were expected to find them by hand.